# How to include a variable in a field in sql statement using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a php script to query a MYSQL database. However, I may have a syntax error that makes my code not work.

If I do not use a variable and subsitute $errType  for 'version'(for example), everything works fine.  I am having issues with using a variable in place for a field.

```
 $errType = $_POST['errorCategory'];
 $errType = $mysqli->real_escape_string($errType);

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM codecError WHERE '$errType' ='0' ";
 $result = $mysqli -> query($sql);
 $count = $result -> num_rows;

 if($count > 0){
 }
```

Comment: Which error is reported by php?

Comment: Do *not* create SQL queries like this. Use [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: @Phylogenesis in this case what would it be?

Comment: Can you show some `codecError` table data... and what comes to php in `$_POST['errorCategory']` ?

Comment: `$errType` is a column? Is PHP reporting a `syntax error`?

Comment: its better to echo your query `echo $sql = "SELECT * FROM codecError WHERE '$errType' ='0' ";` and run this on php myadmin, chk either working or not?

Comment: Per the update, `$errType = 'version';` has the same behavior?

Comment: than run this query in phpmyadmin `SELECT * FROM codecError WHERE version ='0'` and chk getting result or not?

Comment: @chris - same. sql statement does not work. but direct replacement with 'version' does work.

Comment: than chk your connection,

Comment: Well `'version'` is a string (in SQL), `version` or that surrounded by backticks is a column.

Comment: Column names should not be quoted with single quotes. Use backticks for column names. `\`$errType\``

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Comment: you must not add space between `$mysqli` & `->` and `->` & `query()` (and the same on the following line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you mean?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM codecError WHERE {$errType} ='0'";
```

You could also write it as

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM codecError WHERE ".$errType." ='0'";
```

Comment: Did you check the SQL Syntax? Furthermore $mysqli -> cannot work, as well as with $result... In case that you have spaces here, not sure if it is just a formatting issue.

Comment: All three cases are the same. OP is using double quotes.

Comment: @dave you say it does not work but accept it as an answer ?